# Overload private constructor with polymorphic arguments in Scala

Tags: scala, scala.js

I'm curious what the best solution to something like this is in Scala:

```
class MyClass private (x: Any, y: Int) {
  def this(x: Int, y: Int) = this(x, y)
  def this(x: String, y: Int) = this(x, y)
}

val x0 = new MyClass(1, 1)
val x1 = new MyClass("1", 1)
//val x2 = new MyClass(1.0, 1) // Correctly doesn't typecheck
```

The error below doesn't make a lot of sense to me, because it appears that a viable constructor is defined before the auxiliary constructor:

```
Error:(3, 31) called constructor's definition must precede calling constructor's definition
  def this(x: Int, y: Int) = this(x, y)
                         ^
```

For more context, I'm actually trying to deal with JavaScript APIs in Scala.js with functions that take a parameter that can be either a `String` or as `js.Object`, but I think this exemplifies the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ascribing the type to `Any` explicitly will help:

```
class MyClass private (x: Any, y: Int) {
  def this(x: Int, y: Int) = this(x: Any, y)
  def this(x: String, y: Int) = this(x: Any, y)
}
```

In your case, the constructors would call themselves recursively, which is obviously nonsensical.

Comment: ... I didn't know I could do that. I tried something similar but more verbose, which probably failed for an unrelated reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I never worked with Scala-js, but could this solve your problem:

```
class MyClass private (x: Any, y: Int)

object MyClass{
  def apply(x:Int,y:Int) = new MyClass(x,y)
  def apply(x:String, y:Int) = new MyClass(x,y)
}


val x0 = MyClass(1, 1)
val x1 = MyClass("1", 1)
//val x2 = new MyClass(1.0, 1) // Correctly doesn't typecheck
```

Comment: This would be a viable option in Scala indeed. However, OP is trying to create a facade for an existing JavaScript library IIUC. That means the code you see above is only for typing purposes and does not actually generate anything. Therefore, OP cannot adapt the structure of it.